# Insert 2 numbers into a byte

Tags: c#

I need to insert 2 bits of data into a single byte.

First 3 bits (0,1,2) to contain a number between 1 and 5.

Last 5 bits (3,4,5,6,7) to contain a number between 0 and 25.  [Edit: Changed from 250]

I tried:

```
byte mybite = (byte)(val1 & val2)
```

but to be honest I don't really know what I'm doing with bit operations although I had some help in reading this info from an earlier post which was great.

This is how I read the info from a byte:

```
 // Advanced the position of the byte by 3 bits and read the next 5 bits
 ushort Value1 = Convert.ToUInt16((xxx >> 3) & 0x1F);

 // Read the first 3 bits
 ushort Value2 = Convert.ToUInt16((xxx & 0x7));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By casting UInt16 to one single byte you have to be careful not to cut off the first byte != 0. Your compiler will give you a warning certainly.

Comment: You cannot store a number between 0 and 250 in 5 bits.

Comment: Can you please explain how do you want to store values in the range 0 - 250 in five bits?

Comment: You can only store a number between 0 and 63 in 5 bits.

Comment: @chrischu You mean 0 and 31 right? 0-63 requires 6 bits..

Comment: Sorry, the number will be between 0 and 25.... I forgot that I multiply the number by 10 once I have it.

Comment: @user1429080 Damn typical off-by-one error. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: @Anonymous Please edit 250 to 25 - I had to read all the comments to see that you are notified about the error.

Comment: While the math here can be fun, have you considered using the BitArray class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ty2t3fx.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int num1 = 4;
int num2 = 156;
int num = (num2 << 3) | num1;
```

Then you can read `num2` by shifting 3 to the right

```
int num2Read = num >> 3
```

And you read `num1` like (you are creating something like a mask that &'s the first 3 bits of num)

```
int num1Read = num & 7
```

This way, the first number can be 3 bits and the second number can be arbitrarily long

Comment: I think you need 7 instead of 15 when reading the second value back.

Answer (score 1):

(If I understand your question , you want to add bits to a certain location)
Byte is `xxxx-xxxx`

so if you want to "add" to the right most bit : `xxxx-xxxY`

`byte b=...`

`b=b | 1`

If you want to add to the second most right bit : `xxxx-xxYx`

`b=b | 2`

If you want to add to the third most right bit : `xxxx-xYxx`

`b=b | 4`

If you want to add to the fourth most right bit : `xxxx-Yxxx`

`b=b | 8`

If you want to add to the fifth most right bit : `xxxY-xxxx`

`b=b | 16`

differnet example :

if you want to add 14 :

just do

`b=b | 14`
which will upbit the  `xxxx-YYYx` bits

Comment: For the sake of completeness you should also post the non-trivial case of setting the third most right bit: `b = b | 4`.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I think its pretty obvious...:-)

Comment: ...for someone who describes himself like this: *but to be honest I don't really know what I'm doing with bit operations* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `or` instead of `and` operation. IE

```
byte mybite = (byte)(val1 | val2);
```

If val1 is 0000-0010 (2) and val2 is 1000-0000 (128), `and` (`&`) will result in 0000-0000, while `or` (`|`) will result in 1000-0010 (130).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you are looking for a reverse operation to the one you had in you question.

Here is how you can do that (ugly code with casts etc, but shows what's happening with the bits):

```
byte source = 0xA3; // source = 10100011 = 163
// get bits from source
byte lowbits = (byte)((int)source & 7); // lowbits = 00000011 = 3
byte highbits = (byte)((int)source >> 3); // highbits = 00010100 = 20
```

Note though that at this point, `lowbits` contains a value that is between 0 and 7 (*not 0 and 5*), while `highbits` contains a value that is between 0 and 31 (*not 0 and 250*).

```
// use bits to create copy of original source
byte destination = (byte)(((int)highbits << 3) | (int)lowbits); // destination = 10100011
```

Also note that if `highbits` contains a value greater than 31, then some bits will be dropped by this operation. And if `lowbits` contain a value greater than 7, it *may* cause some bits from `highbits` to be overwritten.